# Mozilla и Opera не отображают шрифты после заливки на хост

Tags: html

Есть страница на html. На локалке все нормально, но когда на хост заливаю, Mozilla и Opera шрифты все типа кубиков делают, но с Google Chrome все нормально отображается. Что делать?
Пробовал и на другом компе, одна и та же проблема.

Comment: Возможно, ответы на ваш вопрос есть уже тут: [DOCTYPE](http://htmlbook.ru/html/!doctype).

Comment: Добавьте head html-документа в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Еще как вариант(но маловероятный) - указать кодировку. Например:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Пересоздайте HTML страницу. Создайте .txt файл, скопируйте туда HTML код и сохраните в кодировке UTF-8(Если шрифты русские), если нет - то в кодировке 1250 ANSI. (Возможно вариант с UTF-8 и для не русских шрифтов прокатит, незнаю точно).
Потом в HTML страницу добавьте "!doctype" с выбраной кодировкой. Ну и как было вышесказано можете попробывать добавить <meta> тег.